# Google Maps Dynamic Embed

Tags: php, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

I would like to simply ask if anyone can help me identify the issue with my code.

I am trying to display a dynamic google maps to simply show the location of every event in my website.

I did some research on it and google kindly gave this code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide):

```
<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=API_KEY&q=record+stores+in+Seattle">
```

And then modified to suit my needs.

```
<iframe width="700" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/**MODE**?key=**API_KEY**&q=<?php echo $row['location'];"></iframe>
```

Now I have put the mode as search and put my developer's API key as well. I assume that q="location"

But in the end when I click on the page it only displays the map showing the whole world:

[Image of Error](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=312u7tj&s=8#.VGav2_mUdqU)

and as you can see I have Location: 123 Clarance Street, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia

which I've basically did is:

```
Location: <?php echo $row['location']?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=API_KEY&q=123+Clarence+Street,+Sydney,+New+South+Wales,+Australia">
```

Just to test if there was something wrong with the PHP code. So at the moment Im stumped and don't know where to look as a lot of the things people are asking online and their solutions didn't help me in my solution.

I'm sure it could be something minor, but just hoping someone out there can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, there is simply no guarantee that google will find a result for each query. When you e.g. remove the "Australia" you'll get a result.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much for that info. I didn't try attempting to take off the Country. Now I got the map working hopefully the queries will be all okay :)

Comment: Is there a way to test if google maps query found the location or showing whole world map ? I would like to change the query and try again if result not found :)